# Ruby on Rails Activerecord undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am new to the Ruby on Rails.

in controller

```
@academic_record = AcademicDetailWeb.where(:term => @sel_term, :sysid=>session[:user_credentials_sysid])
```

in the view

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>CRN</th>
    </tr>
    <%@academic_record.each do |a|%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= @academic_record.crn %>
           </td>
        </tr>
    <%end%>
</table>
```

it give me "undefined method `crn' for activerecord"

I tried to use

```
@academic_record.first.crn
```

and it works, but only shows the first record

How could I modify it to become several row records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the collection of records while inside the loop. Change that to refer to one element of the collection:

```
<% @academic_record.each do |a|%>
  <%= a.crn %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

@academic_record is a collection of the academic details according to your condition and inside each collection each data contains crn attribute..crn is an attribute of each member of this collection, not the collection as a whole, thats why when you use @academic_record.first.crn it gives crn of first element inside that collection and when you use @academic_record.crn it gives you undefined method, cuz there isn't any crn attribute of the collection as whole so you should do something like

```
<% @academic_record.each do |ar|%>
  <%= ar.crn %>
<% end %>
```